Why is the error in a Taylor series sometimes written as a big O and sometimes a small O
I'm trying to use Euler's method for the first time, and in its derivation our class book used the little oh notation to refer to the quadratic term when you have
$y(t_1) = y(t_0) + hy'(t_0) + \frac{y''(ε)}{2!}h^2 $
To be rewritten as
$y(t_1) = y(t_0) + hy'(t_0) + o(h^2) $
Which then is approximated to
$y(t_1) ≈ y(t_0) + hy'(t_0) $
For small enough values of the step $h$.
I wasn't familiar with this notation before so I had to look at the definitions but I don't understand why our book specifically uses the little oh notation instead of big oh like the books I found in the references. What I initially got from our class' book is that, the error will approach zero more rapidly than the linear function when I take
$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{y(t_1) - y(t_0) - hy'(t_0)} {h^2} = ∞ $
So when I take steps $h$ that get increasingly smaller in the algorithm, up to a certain point, I will be able to get a smaller error in the approximation.
But I think I understood it wrong, is the notation not referring to the last term itself? Like, does that just say that $\frac{y''(ε)}{2!}h^2$ goes to infinity slower than $h^2$? Which also doesn't make much sense to me since they should go to infinity at the same speed right?
I also don't quite understand why our book chose to write it with the small oh instead of the big oh, or if that was a mistake.

Little $o$ works like "$<$", big $O$ works like "$\leq$". It seems to me your book is using incorrect notation since there can be a nonzero $h^2$ term, and big-$O$ would be the correct terminology.

FYI - just like inserting "^" gives you superscripts in LaTeX, inserting "_" gives you subscripts: $t_1$ and $t_0$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

I appreciate the assistance, thanks a ton fellas :)
